# Is it possible to get a response as a json file instead of making him a jsonobject in java?

Tags: java, android

So i have a get request from an API, when i get the response i want to make that response into a json file instead of making him an JSONOBJECT, is it possible ? i will paste the get funcion here, and the way im getting the JSONOBJECT.
I want to replace the way i get a JSONOBJECT, from a way to get that json as a file that goes to my assets directory.

```
public void getAssetPlant(final VolleyCallBack callBack) {
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url_assets, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject j = new JSONObject(response);
                    callBack.onSuccess();
                } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                


            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "Failed to gather info" + error.networkResponse.statusCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
                return headers;
            }
        };
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }
```

Comment: You can not add a file in Assets at runtime . You can not get a json file as response .
You can create a file in local storage and write the response in it .. Why you need a File anyway ? can u explain little bit maybe there a better solution for your problem .

Comment: Yes, i need the json to use a method in azure maps that adds a geojson file into a datasource, as importdatafromurl. I tryed to add as json object or string and it wont acept, i can only open from a file in my dir or from web link.

Comment: then try writing a file with response in local storage and pass the path to that client . you can lots of questions on How and where to write a a file in android .